# difference between 'Azure' and 'AzureServicePrincipal' in -ConnectionTypeName

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

1)What is the difference between 'Azure' and 'AzureServicePrincipal' in -ConnectionTypeName in New-AzureRMAutomationConnection ?
2) when to use 'Azure' and when to use 'AzureServicePrinciple' ?

Comment: Are you trying to use Automation account for any tasks? There's a switch to create AzureRunAsConnection which can authenticate with Azure without using the `New-AzureRmAutomationConnection` cmdlet

Comment: Yes, I am trying to automate the Runbook and constantly getting error when using AzureServicePrincipal in Connectiontypename, inspite of all the right values of "AutomationCertificateName"="aaCertificate"; "ApplicationId" = $Application; "TenantId" = $TenantID; "CertificateThumbprint" = $Cert; "SubscriptionId" = $SubscriptionId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question (+1), Actually I also tried to figure out the answer to your question for many days, but guess what! Microsoft itself doesn't have enough documentation to explain this.

Actually, there are 3 different connection types

1. Azure
2. Azure Service Principal
3. Azure Classic Certificate

### Azure Service Principal (Azure Run As Account)

> Azure Run As Account - This account is used to manage Resource Manager
>   deployment model resources.

### Azure Classic Certificate (Azure Classic Run As Account)

> This account is used to manage Classic deployment model resources.

You can find the full details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account)

But regarding the connection type as `Azure` is not able to find from any Microsoft official docs

So, I open an Issue regarding the same at Github.

You can track that below

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7048

Answer (score 0):

So as you are trying to Automate the Runbook, you can use the below script for Authenticating with Azure inside your workflow/script. Create Automation account using `Create AzureRunAsAccount` as **Yes**. [image]

Then you can include this piece of code in your workflow.

```
Write-Output "------------------------ Authentication ------------------------"
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try {
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection) {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    }
    else {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
## End of authentication
```